# Xcode Project #include <cmath>

Tags: xcode, include, objective-c++

I'm trying to use code that already works in another standalone project without problems.

When I bring this code into my other final project, it indicate that 'cmath' file not found.

The file with the  #include  is in an .hpp file (it just defines some structs for opengl stuff), so there is not a corresponding .mm file. (This is C++ code and I'm mainly an objective-c user so not sure of all the c++ stuff)
But this is for opengl stuff and works fine we not in this project.

I've tried everything to make this work.

The final project with the problem has other code that uses #include  without problems.
It is almost like something is causing xcode not to recognize the path the header anymore.
I've checked its file type it is "Default C++ header"

In the final project I'm using Zxing and also using CorePlots. Not sure if they are causing any problems. Also some file are using #include  not sure if that could conflict with the #incude  or not. (But again the other files with #include  are working fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternately to Jon Reid's good advice you can pick "Compile as Objective-C++" in the Build Settings. (Search for "Compile sources" in the Build Settings window.) This is a little bit wild-west but is a quick way to see if the problem is in fact your C++ source compiling as C or Objective-C

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that switch.

Answer (score 4):

Your header file doesn't exist by itself; something must import it. Rename the importing files, changing their file types from .m to .mm.

For example, let's say your header that includes <cmath> is named foo.h. And that this in turn is used by a `bar` module, composed of bar.h and bar.m. So foo.h is imported in either bar.h or bar.m.

Rename bar.m to bar.mm so that it uses C++. Do the same for all .m files that depend on foo.h.

Comment: I tried that and still having the problem. But the .mm file is a UIViewController with a .xib does the .xib have any effect on this?

Comment: No.
Try buildsucceeded's answer to apply the C++ compiler across the entire project, in case you missed another .mm rename

Comment: This is probably a better answer, especially if you are using C code in your project too.